# Trying to plot a defined function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a problem. I'm trying to plot a function for different values of `d`. I have defined `d` as:

```
d = np.arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.01)
```

But I still get the same error:

> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

This is my script:

```
import pylab
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy

def teo_function(d):
    return 2*math.pi*math.sqrt(((1**2)/(12+d**2))/9.81*d)

d = np.arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.01)
T = teo_function(d)
pylab.plot (d,teo_function(d), 'bo', d, teo_function(d), 'k')

pylab.show()
```

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 4):

You have to vectorize your function `teo_function` to work with an array:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def teo_function(d):
    return 2*math.pi*math.sqrt(((1**2)/(12+d**2))/9.81*d)
vecfunc = np.vectorize(teo_function)

d = np.arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.01)
T = vecfunc(d)
plt.plot (d, T, 'bo', d, T, 'k')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Holy christ! THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

the function `teo_function` uses `math.sqrt` which works on scalars, not on arrays. If you ever use numpy arrays, use the math operations which are included in `numpy`, eg. `numpy.sqrt`. Numpy has equivalent to all functions i know in the `math.module` optimized for use in numpy arrays.

Numpy's functions will also work on scalars, lists, tuples and more types.

eg:

```
def teo_function(d):
    return 2*np.pi*np.sqrt(((1**2)/(12+d**2))/9.81*d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way. If you want your function to return a list

```
def teo_function(ds):
    return [2*math.pi*math.sqrt(((1**2)/(12+d**2))/9.81*d) for d in ds]
```